# Plesk XML formatting

Tags: php, xml, plesk

In PHP i have this code for making a XML header for the plesk API.

```
$request = <<<EOF
<packet version="1.6.7.0">
<mail>
<update>
   <set>
      <filter>
         <site-id>$site_id</site-id>
         <mailname>
            <name>$name</name>
            <autoresponder>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
               <subject>$subject</subject>
               <text>$mail_body</text>
               <end_date>$date</end_date>
            </autoresponder>
         </mailname>
      </filter>
   </set>
</update>
</mail>
</packet>
EOF;
```

However i get this response:  1014 Parser error: Cannot parse the XML from the source specified

I have put the xml into a formatting of 2, 3 ,4 and tab spacing and it doesnt seem to be able to parse it.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't guess to create a valid XML by string concatenation, especially when you have complex contents like an email text.

No all characters are allowed inside XML tags: you have to properly escape not-allowed characters. Fortunately, php have some parser that do this job for you.

First of all, create an empty XML template (check its validity using a [XML validator](https://validator.w3.org/check)):

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<packet version="1.6.7.0">
<mail>
<update>
    <set>
        <filter>
            <site-id/>
            <mailname>
                <name/>
                <autoresponder>
                    <enabled/>
                    <subject/>
                    <text/>
                    <end_date/>
                </autoresponder>
            </mailname>
        </filter>
    </set>
</update>
</mail>
</packet>
';
```

Then, load it into a `DOMDocument` object and init a `DOMXPath` object:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
```

Then, find each node that you want to change and set/update its node value:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query( 'mail/update/set/filter/site-id' );
$nodes->item(0)->nodeValue = $site_id;

$nodes = $xpath->query( 'mail/update/set/filter/mailname/name' );
$nodes->item(0)->nodeValue = $name;
```

For the `<autoresponder>` children, you can perform a loop through each child, using `*` at the end of your search pattern:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query( 'mail/update/set/filter/mailname/autoresponder/*' );
foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    if( 'enabled' == $node->nodeName )
    {
        $node->nodeValue = 'true';
    }
    elseif( 'subject' == $node->nodeName )
    {
        $node->nodeValue = $subject;
    }
    elseif( 'text' == $node->nodeName )
    {
        $cdata = $dom->createCDATASection( $mail_body );
        $node->appendChild( $cdata );
    }
    elseif( 'end_date' == $node->nodeName )
    {
        $node->nodeValue = $date;
    }
}
```

Note the different syntax adopted for mail body: I use a `CDATA` node here: if your XML doesn't allow `CDATA`, replace it with standard `->nodeValue` syntax. Or — instead — you can have to use `CDATA` method for all the nodes.

When the XML is ready, you can echo it by:

```
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

`DOMXPath` allow to perform complex searches in the XML tree: it's not mandatory in your case, because you start from a short, empty, unambiguous template. I use it for demonstration purpose, but you can replace a line like this:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query( 'mail/update/set/filter/site-id' );
```

with:

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'site-id' );
```

and it will work fine.

---

- Read more about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- Read more about [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)